# git-flow push non ready feature on remote git server

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow, git-workflow

I use git flow methodology and i need advice on how to push non ready feature on remote git server.

By default we can do it in such way (If feature has finished)

```
git checkout -b feature develop
Do something...
git commit -am "Message"
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature
git push origin develop
git push origin feature
```

What if my feature is not ready, but i want push it on remote server?

I have tried to do it in such way:

```
 git checkout -b feature develop
 Do something...
 git commit -am "Message"
 git push origin feature
```

But if i look at graphic scheme of commits it seems like develop and feature are the same branch (But of course they are not the same).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *publish* the feature:

```
$ git flow feature publish <name_of_feature>
```

Take a look at this [git flow cheat sheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. But i am looking for how to do it without flow. I want to have approach on how can i make it by using native git commands.

Comment: Ok, it's sufficient to "translate" that command on git-flow in simple git commands.

Removing some checks (if yet exists on remote repo etc.):

    git push origin name_of_feature:refs/heads/name_of_feature
    git fetch -q origin
    git config "branch.name_of_feature.remote" origin
    git config "branch.name_of_feature.merge" "refs/heads/name_of_feature"

Comment: @robdex: Why not simply do a  `git push --set-upstream origin name_of_feature`  and let Git handle the upstream registration itself in the repository configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more here, for comparison etc

https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac